# How to remove overlapping bevel in a triangle

Tags: bevel

I'm just starting out with Blender so apologies in advance if this is something very trivial I'm simply overlooking.
I've created this triangle below using a cylinder with 3 vertices. When I apply a `bevel` to it then I can't figure out how to remove the overlapping effect that happens in the corners where two edges meet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's normal.  The bevel has to meet and I think that's the normal way for it to intersect.  Do you have smooth shading on?  That might make it look better

Comment: sometimes you need to do it manually (it means you need first to apply the modifier)

Comment: Lower numer of segments - 40 is waaay too high.
It's a quite sharp angle where different faces are meeting as @RBlong2us pointed out.
To get a smoother result: change  Bevel / Geometry / Miter Inner to Arc (default is Sharp)